# How to traverse JSON file during Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, builder

Jackson deserialization of the following combination of JSON string and a corresponding Java file works fine:

```
String json = "{'text': 'what is my balance', 'mid': 'D1dexnEBTCefEdRWveEt8A', 'seq': 73}";
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Messages.MessageBuilder.class)
public class Message implements Serializable {

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public final String id;

  @JsonProperty("botId")
  public final String botId;

  @JsonProperty("userId")
  public final String userId;

  public final String userIdKey;

  public boolean echoText=false;

  public String text;

  public String timeZone;

  public volatile String username;

  @JsonProperty("conversationId")
  public volatile String conversationId;

  public volatile int kaiUserId;

  public volatile String token;

  public final LocalDateTime inboundReceivedAt;

  public volatile LocalDateTime outboundSentAt;

  final String key;

  private final int _hashCode;

  public volatile long lastAccess = System.currentTimeMillis();

  public Message(final String pMessageId, final String pUserId, final String pBotId, final String pConversationId, final String pText) {
    id = pMessageId;
    userId = pUserId;
    botId = pBotId;
    conversationId = pConversationId;
    text = pText;
    inboundReceivedAt = LocalDateTime.now();

    key = id + "-" + userId + "-" + botId;
    userIdKey = userId + "~" + botId;

    _hashCode = key.hashCode();
  }

  void touch() { lastAccess = System.currentTimeMillis(); }

  @Override public int hashCode() { return _hashCode; }

  @Override public boolean equals(final Object pObject) {
    if (!(pObject instanceof Message)) { return false; }
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(id, ((Message)pObject).id)
                              .append(botId, ((Message)pObject).botId)
                              .append(userId, ((Message)pObject).userId)
                              .isEquals();
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
}
```

and produces the desired Message object with its `text` and `id` fields populated with values from the above JSON file.

However, when trying to map the following JSON string:

```
String json = "{'entry': [{'messaging': [{'timestamp': 123123123121, "
                + "'message': {'text': 'what is my balance', 'mid': 'D1dexnEBTCefEdRWveEt8A', 'seq': 73}, "
                + "'recipient': {'id': 'kai'}, 'sender': {'id': 'test'}}], "
                + "'id': 'PAGE_ID', 'time': 145645454454}], 'object': 'page'}";
```

of which the original JSON is just a subset, the resulting `Message` object now misses the values (they are assigned **null**) in the same `text` and `id` fields.

Here are all the additional pieces of the Jackson mapping infrastructure I use:

```
/**
 * Jackson backed implementation of {@link Serializer}
 */
public final class JacksonSerializer implements Serializer {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
    }

    /**
     * For testing purposes.
     */
    static void setMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        mapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> String serialize(T t) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Serialization error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void serialize(T object, OutputStream outputStream) {
        try {
            mapper.writeValue(outputStream, object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Serialization error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void serialize(T object, File file) {
        try {
            mapper.writeValue(file, object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Serialization error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T deserialize(String s, Class<T> aClass) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(s, aClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Deserialization error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T deserialize(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> type) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(inputStream, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Deserialization error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T deserialize(File file, Class<T> type) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(file, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabindException("Deserialization error", e);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public final class Messages {


    private Messages(){}

    public static MessageBuilder standard() {
        return new MessageBuilder();
    }



    public final static class MessageBuilder {

        @JsonProperty("mid")
        String id;

        String userId;
        String botId;
        String conversationId;

        @JsonProperty("text")
        String text;



        public MessageBuilder withId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("userId")
        public MessageBuilder withUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("botId")
        public MessageBuilder withBotId(String botId) {
            this.botId = botId;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("conversationId")
        public MessageBuilder withConversationId(String conversationId) {
            this.conversationId = conversationId;
            return this;
        }

        public MessageBuilder withText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
            return this;
        }

        public Message build() {
            Message result = null;
            result = new Message(id, userId, botId, conversationId, text);
            return result;
        }

    }

    public final static class PushMessageBuilder{

    }
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void deserializationTest() {
    Serializer serializer = new JacksonSerializer();

        String json = "{'entry': [{'messaging': [{'timestamp': 123123123121, "
            + "'message': {'text': 'what is my balance', 'mid': 'D1dexnEBTCefEdRWveEt8A', 'seq': 73}, "
            + "'recipient': {'id': 'kai'}, 'sender': {'id': 'test'}}], "
            + "'id': 'PAGE_ID', 'time': 145645454454}], 'object': 'page'}";
    /*String json = "{'text': 'what is my balance', 'mid': 'D1dexnEBTCefEdRWveEt8A', 'seq': 73}";*/
    Message message = serializer.deserialize(json, Message.class);
```

I am wondering if it is possible to declare the `@JsonProperty`'s annotation value in the `MessageBuilder.java` (or perhaps there's a better solution) in such a way that Jackson parser knows how to traverse the JSON hierarchy and extract just the necessary item from it when mapping it into the Java object, i.e.: `@JsonProperty("entry.messaging.message.text")` or something to that effect.

I'm using jackson version 2.9.4

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please don't violate JSON spec.String literals (and field names) are not enclosed by `'` but with `"`.

Comment: @rkosegi thank you, but this is irrelevant to the question and is allowed by Jackson.